# How to transform Haskell type family to Idris type function?

Tags: haskell, idris

Suppose we have some Haskell type family which maps types to some other types:

```
data (a :: Type) :+: (b :: Type) = a :+: b

type family MapType (a :: Type) :: Type

type instance MapType Int = Integer
type instance MapType Integer = Integer
type instance MapType (a :+: b) = (MapType a, MapType b)

class HasConvert a where
  convert :: Proxy a -> a -> MapType a
  
instance (HasConvert a, HasConvert b) => HasConvert (a :+: b) where
  convert :: Proxy (a :+: b) -> (a :+: b) -> (MapType a, MapType b)
  convert _ (a :+: b) = (convert (Proxy @a) a, convert (Proxy @b) b)

-- etc etc
```

How to write an Idris equivalent for this? If I start writing like this:

```
MapType : Type -> Type
MapType Int = Integer
```

then it fails to compile because Idris cannot pattern match on types.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using Idris 1 or 2?

Comment: Idris 1 for now.

Comment: It should be clear that this would only be a _partial_ function anyway. (Which I suppose you can have in Idris, though you can't in Coq.)

Comment: I think it requires Idris 2

Comment: Yes, it's clear that it's a partial function.

Comment: would it be acceptable to instead have a something like `MapType : (a : Type ** (a = Int)) -> Type`?

Comment: Why not :) but is it some better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your use-case is something like:

```
data MapTypeProof : Type -> Type where                                         
  Proof0 : (a = Int) -> MapTypeProof a                                       
  Proof1 : (a = Integer) -> MapTypeProof a                                     
  Proof2 : (c = (a :+: b))                                                    
         -> MapTypeProof a                                                   
         -> MapTypeProof b                                                   
         -> MapTypeProof c

MapType : MapTypeProof a -> Type
MapType (Proof2 _ p q)  = (MapType p, MapType q)
MapType _ = Integer

MapType' : (a : Type ** MapClassProof a) -> Type
MapType' (_ ** mcp) = MapClass mcp
```

could work. Calling the function would look like: `MapType Int (Proof0 Refl)`.

Comment: ...and how to add the rest, I mean type instance MapType Integer = Integer
type instance MapType (a :+: b) = (MapType a, MapType b)